# Phase diagram for empirical data

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, visualization

The behaviour of partial or ordinary differential equations can be studied/visualized with phase diagrams. How would one plot such diagrams for empirical data, which are suspected to be governed by differential equations?

Suppose I have e.g. some time-series data. Should I plot the original series $x_n$ against first differences $\dot{x} = x_{n+1}-x_{n}$, or do something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that with "[phase diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_diagram)" you mean the "[phase portrait](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_portrait)" of your system (the plot of typical trajectories in the "state space").

Therefore, if the state space of your system is the space of the points $(x,\dot{x})$, then the answer to your question is YES.

Since you have $(t^q_i,x^q_i)$, where $q$ is the label of a specific trajectory, you have to plot (for all the $q$ trajectories) the points $(x^q_i,v^q_i)$, where

$$
v_i^q = f( ...x_{i-1}^q,x_i^q,x_{i+1}^q... ; ...t_{i-1}^q,t_i^q,t_{i+1}^q... )
$$

is a certain discrete approximation of the velocity along the trajectory $q$. There are some dots, indicating that the number of arguments depends on the "[stencil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Five-point_stencil)" you want to use to calculate the derivative.

For example, simple possibilities are:

$$
v_i^q \approx \frac{x_{i+1}^q-x_{i}^q}{t_{i+1}^q-t_{i}^q} \approx \frac{x_{i}^q-x_{i-1}^q}{t_{i}^q-t_{i-1}^q} \approx \frac{x_{i+1}^q-x_{i-1}^q}{t_{i+1}^q-t_{i-1}^q}
$$

Of course you can consider higher-order methods to calculate the derivative (this is why in the definition of $f$ there are some dots).

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I mean the phase portrait. If a state-space is defined as a set of all possible configurations of the system, I'm not sure if I can ever be sure what that is for empirical data, though. Maybe I just don't get the concepts too well yet. Just starting out here. Anyway, thanks for the help!

Comment: It depends on how your data are collected and what you know about this system (a-priori knowledge or "prejudice"). If your $(t_i,x_i)$ are the output of a simulation, then you known (because you known the algorithm) if the $x_i$ are all the variables needed to define a single point in the state-space. If $(t_i,x_i)$ are measures of a physical phenomena, then you enter in the field pf Physics: depending on the knowledge we have about the observed phenomena, the "prejudice" that $x_i$ define uniquely the state is more or less reliable.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, it was very helpful! I'll think about the situation from that point of view.